# why am i getting: Call to undefined method sfPHPView::getRequestParameter?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

i have this code in listmatchesSuccess.php:

```
$matching_rows = RcProfileTablePeer::getAllBySelection($gender_id1,$gender_id2,$age1,$age2,$province_id);
$pager = new sfPropelPager('RcProfileTable', 10);
$pager->setCriteria($matching_rows);
$pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter('page', 1));
$pager->init();
```

in my actions.class.php i have just the function:

```
public function executeListmatches(sfWebRequest $request)
{

}
```

i just want to list all the rows that matches my search criteria which i select on the main page, i hit a go button then get to listmatches page

the submit button call in _login.php is:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('password/listmatches?page='."1" ) ?>"  method="post" >
```

is it because i do not have those pager rows in my actions.class?
please help?
thank you

Comment: `$this` refers to the current class. Is that code inside a class (listmatchesSuccess.php)?

Comment: According to http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPHPView there is no method called "getRequestParameter".

Comment: ooo yup quite right..no it isnt..i dont know where to put the pager code because the page gets called from inside a partial _login.php via the form action...any advise please? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put the pager code in your view (listmatchesSuccess.php)? It belongs in the action. I strongly recommend doing the Practical Symfony tutorial to understand the MVC model:

[Jobeet Tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/)

The $this->getRequestParameter() is a method from sfAction class so you cannot use it in the view, which is descended from the sfView class. Again - your pager code belongs in actions.class.php.

Here is a tutorial about paging in symfony. It is made for the 1.2 version but it will do just fine.

[Pagination tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/pager)